# org.json.JSONException: No value for list

Tags: android, json

I have problem with volley lib, when I post values to server I got an error

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for taxi_list
```

so when user click the button it will show no data whatsoever
here it is the code:

```
// Creating volley request obj
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, s.toString());

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);

                    if(!jsonObject.getBoolean("error")) {
                        JSONArray taxiJsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("taxi_list");
                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < taxiJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject obj = taxiJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            Taxi taxi = new Taxi();
                            taxi.settaxiname(obj.getString("taxiname"));
                            taxi.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                            taxi.setdeparture(obj.getString("departure"));
                            taxi.setarrive(obj.getString("arrive"));
                            taxi.setseat(obj.getInt("seat"));
                            taxi.setcost(obj.getInt("cost"));

                            // adding taxi to taxi array
                            taxiList.add(taxi);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // notifying list adapter about data changes
                // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Requesting Taxi Error: " + volleyError.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        })
```

and this is my json;

```
    {
  "error": false,
  "taxi_list": [
    {
      "image": "http://localhost/androidapp/taxiprofile/1.jpg",
      "taxiname": "Taxi 1",
      "from": "PTK",
      "to": "SGU",
      "departure": "08:00:00",
      "arrive": "13:00:00",
      "seat": 7,
      "cost": 12
    },
    {
      "image": "http://localhost/androidapp/taxiprofile/default.jpg",
      "taxiname": "Taxi 2",
      "from": "PTK",
      "to": "SGU",
      "departure": "08:00:00",
      "arrive": "13:00:00",
      "seat": 2,
      "cost": 15
    },
    {
      "image": "http://localhost/androidapp/taxiprofile/2.jpg",
      "taxiname": "Taxi Untung Selalu",
      "from": "PTK",
      "to": "SGU",
      "departure": "09:00:00",
      "arrive": "14:00:00",
      "seat": 3,
      "cost": 13
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried to modify the code, but with no success....
here is the logcat:

```
D/Searching: {"error":false}
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for taxi_list
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:544)
W/System.err:     at com.testing.activity.Searchtaxi$4.onResponse(Searchtaxi.java:177)
W/System.err:     at com.testing.activity.Searchtaxi$4.onResponse(Searchtaxi.java:168)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:67)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the error refers to JSONArray taxiJsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("taxi_list") line

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if you face any issues@meeftah

Comment: Debug this  if(!jsonObject.getBoolean("error")) and see what u got... use debugger...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
jsonObject.getString("error") == false
```

because false is not a string.

Comment: you try with exactly this line and didnt work? because you edit your post with getBoolean("false")

Comment: hi, thanks for answering :), yes I've tried your code but I still get same error

Comment: in your response did you get some values from taxi_list you printet with this line  Log.d(TAG, s.toString()); what you getted ?

Comment: after, I search for a while...apparently I'm not getting taxi_list, how to get taxi_list as my JSONObject?

Comment: your logic is correct for getting taxi_list but i think your response is wrong and you dont get taxi_list at all(you havent data in this taxi_list), i think you can try to modify your logic in your json response not in java class?

Comment: do you mean in my php?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107515/discussion-between-kristiyan-varbanov-and-meeftah).

Answer (score 1):

```
if (jsonObject.getBoolean("error")==false)
```

false is not string

Answer (score 1):

`error` is `boolean` value, try with

```
if(!jsonObject.getBoolean("error"))
```

Comment: have you used ! ?? because if you will just write `if(jsonObject.getBoolean("error"))` it will be same as `error=true`, so you nust use `!`

Comment: thn you should check by printing your response also, error says you are not getting `taxi_list`

Comment: printing my response...how I do that?

Comment: you have already did it `Log.d(TAG, s.toString());` check what are you getting in this line

Comment: after, I search for a while...apparently I'm not getting taxi_list, how to get taxi_list as my JSONObject?

Answer (score 1):

Try checking `key` first like this then get `JsonArray`

```
if (jsonObject.has("taxi_list")) {
 JSONArray taxiJsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("taxi_list");
 } else {
  //show any toast or dialog that taxi list not available.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
if(jsonObject.getBoolean("error"))
```